# Recognize correlated queries when using joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, correlation

I have to write some correlated queries in T-SQL, but I am a kind of data-mining student so I am here with question if this is correlated query

I know that this is correlated query:

```
SELECT score, studentid
FROM Stats.Scores AS S1
WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(S2.score)
    FROM Stats.Scores AS S2
    WHERE S1.testid = S2.testid);
GO
```

But I don't know if this one is correlated:

```
SELECT C.contactname, O.orderid
FROM Sales.Customers AS C
LEFT JOIN Sales.Orders AS O
ON C.custid IN (SELECT O.custid
    WHERE C.custid = O.custid)
ORDER BY O.orderid ASC;
GO
```

In my mind the definition of correlated query says that this is yet another **FROM** matched with **SELECT** in subquery

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second query is as well a `correlated subquery` because

```
ON C.custid IN (SELECT O.custid
    WHERE C.custid = O.custid) <-- Here you are referring the outer table
```

Moreover, your second query will have syntax error cause no `from clause`. You can just do a join on both table for 2nd query (to simplify) like below

```
SELECT C.contactname, O.orderid
FROM Sales.Customers C
LEFT JOIN Sales.Orders O
ON C.custid = O.custid
ORDER BY O.orderid ASC;
```

**Defn:**

In a simple subquery (Non Correlated) you don't need to refer fields(s) from outer table like

```
select col1,col2 from table1 where col1 in (select some_col from table2)
```

In a correlated subquery you use/refer fields from outer query (Like the example you posted).

For more on correlated sybquery see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: Actually the 2nd query does not return any syntax error :o
Thanks :)

Comment: I don't remember the clauses execution order, but it seems that **LEFT JOIN** eliminates requirement of next **FROM** clause

Comment: Yes it's not needed. it will fetch the mentioned fields in query and will display you the result based on join condition. In your case you can go for `inner join` as well.